# c# convert string to dword hex

Tags: c#, string, dword

Can anyone help me how to convert string value to dword hex
for example:

```
string i = "1";
uint32 m = ....
m.toString(X8);
```

so that:
m = 00000001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string i = "1";
UInt32 m;
UInt32.TryParse(i, out m);
string result = m.ToString("X8");
```

or

```
string result = Convert.ToUInt32("1").ToString("X8");
```